# Redux state is returning undefined in component even after redux-logger reports a success dispatch with correct values in payload

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

newbie to Redux here. I'm having trouble accessing values from component props after grabbing values from a backend service. The thing is, the correct values are appearing in redux-logger under the payload and I see a successful dispatch.

Here is my React component:

```
import React from 'react'
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { signIn } from '../../redux'

class SignIn extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.state = {
            emailField: '',
            passwordField: ''
        }
    }

    onEmailChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            emailField: event.target.value
        })
    }

    onPasswordChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            passwordField: event.target.value
        })
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                <Form>
                    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicEmail" onChange={this.onEmailChange}>
                        <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                        <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicPassword" onChange={this.onPasswordChange}>
                        <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                        <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
                    </Form.Group>

                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => {
                            this.props.signIn(this.state.emailField, this.state.passwordField)
                            console.log(this.props.userInfo)                        
                        }
                    }>

                        Submit
                    </Button>

                    <Button variant="primary" onClick={() => this.props.signIn(this.state.signIn(this.emailField, this.passwordField))}>
                        Register
                    </Button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        userInfo: state.userInfo
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return{
        signIn: (emailField, passwordField) => {
            dispatch(signIn(emailField, passwordField))
        }
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignIn)
```

Here is my action:

```
import { SIGN_IN_REQUEST, SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, SIGN_IN_FAILURE } from './signInTypes'
import axios from 'axios'

export const signInRequest = () => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_IN_REQUEST
    }
}

export const signInSuccess = (userInfo) => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_IN_SUCCESS,
        payload: userInfo
    }
}

export const signInFailure = (error) => {
    return {
        type: SIGN_IN_FAILURE,
        payload: error
    }
}

export const signIn = (emailTextField, passwordTextField) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(signInRequest())
        fetch('https://testserver.com/signin', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                email: emailTextField,
                password: passwordTextField
            })
        }).then(response => {
            return response.json()
        }).then(user => {
            if(user.user_id){
                dispatch(signInSuccess(user))
            }
        }).catch(error => {
            dispatch(signInFailure(error.message))
        })
    }
}
```

and here is my reducer:

```
import { SIGN_IN_REQUEST, SIGN_IN_SUCCESS, SIGN_IN_FAILURE } from './signInTypes'

const initialState = {
    loading: false,
    userInfo: {},
    error: ''
}

const signInReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case SIGN_IN_REQUEST:
            return{
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }
        case SIGN_IN_SUCCESS:
            return{
                loading: false,
                userInfo: action.payload,
                error: ''
            }
        case SIGN_IN_FAILURE:
            return {
                loading: false,
                userInfo: {},
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default signInReducer
```

My expectation is that this.props.userInfo should contain the values that the payload contains but unfortunately, it returns undefined.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys may provide!

EDIT:
Here is my rootReducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import signInReducer from './signIn/signInReducer'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    signIn: signInReducer
})

export default rootReducer
```

Comment: How do you combine your reducers? can you share that as well?

Comment: Please paste the combine reducer code in store here

Comment: Thanks, I just posted it in a edit

Comment: - if you have used combine reducer like: {signIn: signInReducer},    then in your component you should change the return statement in mapStateToProps as: userInfo: state.signIn.userInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your root reducer is:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    signIn: signInReducer
})
```

Then `userInfo` is actually inside `state.signIn`, therefore `mapStateToProps` needs to be like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return{
        userInfo: state.signIn.userInfo
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that seems to do the trick. this.props now contains an empty object userInfo. Is there any reason why the values in my payload are not appearing though?

Comment: The only reasons I could see this happening is if the signing request failed or if `user.user_id` is falsy.. can you log the value of user and see if it exists?

Comment: I think user_id is definitely valid. Here is the redux-logger:  {signIn: {…}}signIn: error: ""loading: trueuserInfo: {}__proto__: Object__proto__: Object__proto__: Object
redux-logger.js:1  action     {type: "SIGN_IN_SUCCESS", payload: {…}}payload: email: "sample@gmail.com"first_name: "sample"hash: "$2a$10$ozcdtKCy/gTwPJA/sd4YqOly3b/i7SyVXR1B61dTb.8GkUtGapIj."last_name: "sample"register_date: "2020-03-10T06:05:09.177Z"user_id: 12__proto__: Objecttype: "SIGN_IN_SUCCESS"__proto__: Object

Comment: Either sign in failed or there's a problem in your middleware

Comment: @iostream, you are logging `this.props.userInfo` right after you dispatch a signIn action, and that's why it's empty because you won't see its new value until the next render.. try logging `this.props.userInfo` as the first thing inside `render()` and you will see it updating.

Comment: @ElAoutarHamza Thanks that's exactly what's happening and I see the userInfo object now. Sorry to ask a dumb question, but how do I then use the values immediately after the dispatch is successful?

Comment: You will need to wait for the next render, normally what we do in such case is to use fallback values.. if for example you need to display let's say `this.props.userInfo.email`, you will do something like this: `this.props.userInfo.email || ""`